# How can I dynamically set the background-image on each DIV using ngRepeat and ngClass?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to be able to set the `background-image` property of each `div` that is created during `ng-repeat`.

I tried to use `ng-class` to add the appropriate class to the appropriate div in the `ng-repeat` loop but `ng-class` seems to just be over writing the `.tile` class, which I need to be there.

Also, on a side note, why does all my AngularJS code show up in my source when I view it with Google Dev Tools? You can see all the logic in there. That can't be right, can it?

[image]

How can I get `ng-class` to add the right **class** to the right **div** with out overwriting the  `.tile` class as well as showing up properly in the source?

my Controller in `main.js`

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mmApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.designTiles = [
      { bgImageClass : "best-show-premium", title : "Vance & Gary Unhinged", use : "Album Art" },
      { bgImageClass : "dam-funk", title : "Dam-Funk", use : "Logo" },
      { bgImageClass : "lemy-leopard-soh", title : "Lemy Leopard : Streets of House", use : "Album Art" },
      { bgImageClass : "culture-blind", title : "Max Mythic : Culture Blind", use : "Album Art" },
      { bgImageClass : "future-shock-logo", title : "Future Shock Logo", use : "Logo" },
      { bgImageClass : "fame-logo", title : "F.A.M.E. Logo", use : "Logo" },
      { bgImageClass : "lounge-coffee", title : "Loung Coffee", use : "Album Art" },
      { bgImageClass : "engine-yard-tshirt", title : "Engine Yard T-Shirt", use : "T-shirt Design" },
    ];
  });
```

my `design.html` view

```
<section ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="ng-class: {tile.bgImageClass:true};" class="main">
  <div ng-repeat="tile in designTiles" class="tile">
    <h3 class="tile_title">{{tile.title}}</h3>
    <h4 class="tile_use">{{tile.use}}</h4>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

---

---

### UPDATE

I added the changed that sh0ber suggested. Here is my new `design.html` view

```
<section ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="main">
  <a ng-repeat="tile in designTiles" ng-href="{{tile.url}}" ng-class="['tile', tile.bgImageClass]">
    <h3 class="tile_title">{{tile.title}}</h3>
    <h4 class="tile_use">{{tile.use}}</h4>
  </a>
</section>
```

but this does not actually apply `tile.bgImageClass` to the `<a>` element. Here is what I see in Developer Tools

[image]

If we take a look at the first `<a>` we see

```
<a ng-repeat="tile in designTiles" ng-href="#/design/vance-and-gary-unhinged" ng-class="['tile', 'tile.bgImageClass']" class="ng-scope tile tile.bgImageClass" href="#/design/vance-and-gary-unhinged">
    <h3 class="tile_title ng-binding">Vance &amp; Gary Unhinged</h3>
    <h4 class="tile_use ng-binding">Album Art</h4>
</a>
```

Upon looking at the classes that are applied we see

```
class="ng-scope tile tile.bgImageClass"
```

For this specific `<a>` we should instead see

```
class="ng-scope tile vance-and-gary-unhinged"
```

The `.vance-and-gary-unhinged` class is not being applied right after `.tile`. Why is  `tile.bgImageClass` being placed in there? It seems that AngularJS is not fetching the class. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the binding in the normal class attribute:

```
<section ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="main">
  <div ng-repeat="tile in designTiles" class="tile {{tile.bgImageClass}}">
    <h3 class="tile_title">{{tile.title}}</h3>
    <h4 class="tile_use">{{tile.use}}</h4>
  </div>
</section>
```

<kbd>[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/hahugole/2/edit)</kbd> of the above in action.

Comment: @s3z Try out the demo :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [AngularJS `ng-class` doc:](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)

> The result of the evaluation can be a string representing space
>   delimited class names, an array, or a map of class names to boolean
>   values.

Here I'm using the attribute directive and creating an array of classes. The array contains two classes: one for the class name specified by the `bgImageClass` property and another for the string literal 'tile' for the `tile` class.

```
<section ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="main">
  <div ng-repeat="tile in designTiles" ng-class="[tile.bgImageClass, 'tile']">
      <h3 class="tile_title">{{tile.title}}</h3>
      <h4 class="tile_use">{{tile.use}}</h4>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion and it seems that the proper classes are not being applied to the elements. I changed the HTML a bit. Changed `div` to an `a` and added a `ng-href` directive. Aside from that it's all the same. I added an update to my original post that explains my findings. What do you think is going on?

Comment: Somehow it seems you are using the literal 'tile.bgImageClass', rather than evaluating the variable of the same name.  Can you post a fiddle with your code?